# injecting a call in different module in a controller

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, module

I have created helper class in admincenterintro.ts file

```
module AdminCenterIntroBootstrap.AdminCenterIntro {
'use strict';
export class Main {     
 public static Init = function () {
       alert("Hello World");
    }
}
```

I am trying to inject this the class Main in a controller

```
/// <reference path="../../../js/admincenterintro/admincenterintro.ts" />
module Admin {
'use strict';
 export class SetupGuidanceController {
    public static $inject = ["$rootScope","Main"];

    constructor(private $rootScope: any, private $scope: any, private Main: AdminCenterIntroBootstrap.AdminCenterIntro.Main)
this.Main.Init()
}
```

But when I try calling the Init() method from class Main it shows an error "Init does not exist in type Main". I have also tried calling the Init method directly using AdminCenterIntroBootstrap.AdminCenterIntro.Main.Init(). I get the error FileName: undefined Stack: ReferenceError: 'AdminCenterIntroBootstrap' is undefined

How should i inject this class in to the controller? Can I directly call the Main class method?